# Python & Time functions

Tags: python, sockets, python-2.7, time

I have to check in Python if, for example, in x seconds an action has occurred in Python 2.7. How can I control the time in Python?

I tried with `sleep()` but it doesn't work.

I'm working with sockets and I have to check if in 3 seconds the server send me some data..
I tried this:

```
sock.send(packed_data)

time.sleep(3)

received=sock.recv(61)  

if received == 0:
   ...
```

Comment: Also, what kind of action are you trying to monitor? Button clicks in a UI? Connections to a network port? Changes to the filesystem? All of those have ways to check for things happening over time, but they're all different and there's not going to be a single answer that covers them all.

Comment: Is now my explanation little better?

Comment: `recv` should block, so you don't need the `sleep`. It will wait until data does appear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you considered using settimeout()?

```
sock.send(packed_data)

sock.settimeout(3)

try:
    received=sock.recv(61)  
except socket.timeout:
    ...
```